# TestNG data provider parallel parameter not in code annotation

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider

I have an TestNG test method that is ran with multiple parameters using a data provider:

```
@DataProvider()
public Object[][] scenarios() {...}

@Test(dataProvider = "scenarios")
public void check(...) {...}
```

Sometimes I want to run the `check` tests in parallel and sometimes not. I can control that by setting the code annotation to `@DataProvider(parallel = true)` or `@DataProvider(parallel = false)`, but I want to do that as a run-time parameter, not as a setting in the code.

How can I set if a data provider spawns multiple threads either as a command-line argument or an attribute in the TestNG suite XML file?

Answer (score 2):

[Annotation Transformers](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers) are what you look for.
With them, you will be able to modify the value of `parallel` depending on your own business rule (for example: an env var).

Comment: That seems to work, haven't tried, but great goats, that's a weird meta-hack for something that should be a plain property

Comment: If you want it for all the test campaign, you can use `data-provider-thread-count` attribute on `suite` node of `testng.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to pass ITestContext to data provider and get e.g. groups from test ('singleTest' or 'parallelTest'). In data provider return only one object for singleTest group, it should be enough.